# There's no separation between links in watched tags page

Tags: bug, design, tag-watching

On the [watched/ignored tags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/tag-notifications/current) of the user profile page there is not separation between links:

> [image]

I'm even not sure that the Done link is needed here before Add is tapped.